# Mismatching MCUCR definitions between handbook and AVR-GCC library

Tags: avr, atmega, avr-gcc

The [ATmega8A manual](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZ-f_IyfTQAhXMchQKHX5CCu8QFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2Fimages%2Fatmel-8159-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8a_datasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGF2-u1XCqOhq6IOJvby46j6burmA&sig2=bgMQEPw_3IHEtUOiD5GGBA) defines the bits contained in MCUCR register at page 56.

These definitions don't match the `#define`s contained in the ATmega8A I/O library supplied by avr-gcc, located at `/usr/lib/avr/include/avr/iom8a.h`.

For example, the SE bit (Sleep Enable) is defined in the manual as bit 5, while in the above library it is `#define SE 7`.

I haven't checked if the AVR actually misinterprets these MCUCR flags.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sheet seems to be wrong.

Section "14.8.1. MCUCR – MCU Control Register" on page 56 states
[image]

while section "17.1.1. MCUCR – MCU Control Register" on page 74 states

[image]

which is not possible, since bit 2 and 3 would be ambiguous.

The register summary is correct:

[image]

That means the library definitions are correct.